Problem with combine STM32cubeIDE with PlatformIO
I wanted to use VSC with PlatformIO instead STM32cubeIDE (after configure pin and generate code), but though videos on YT I have problem with finding main.h by VSC - src\Core\Src\main.c:20:10: fatal error: main.h: No such file or directory.
I found solution where someone transfer files from src/Core/Inc to include how it looks and that's work but I don't want to make this after every pin configuration in STM32cubeIDE. Can I change place where STM32cubeIDE saves files in Inc? Or maybe does someone know other solution of this problem?

Use https://github.com/jbaumann/pio_and_stm32cubeide/

You can use this guide to shift from STM32 CubeIDE to CMake based build system with VSCode. Embedded CMake
